# What method would be preferable to use for saving and reading a score from my game?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a method that saves a score in my app. It was previously in the onCreate method, and I thought that was why every time I started the app the users score was set Back to 0. I have since then changed it to an onStart method (line 14-19) which does the exact same thing. Should I be using a different method? I have successfully saved the score, but would I need to call it back within the onStart method?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView1;
    EditText editText1;
    Button button1;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);}

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences score = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = score.edit();
        editor.putInt("key", counter);
        editor.commit();


        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}

    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v == button1){
            counter++;
            editText1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to do that in activity callbacks...just save the data when its changed

Comment: Ok. I'll try doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
1. SharedPreferences or store highscores in a file in storage.
2. Alternately, you can use firbase to store highscores online.
3. Use both of these while keeping in mind internet availability

Comment: Thanks for the options. I will try storing the scores in a file in storage.